# Match everything other than a specific pattern in a number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match everything in a phone number other than a specific pattern.

In the number "07440359359" is there a way to match everything other than "359"?

My main aim with this is to be able to replace the last digit in the number that is not in the pattern.

For example:

With `07440359359` the desired output is `0744*359359`

I've come up with this pattern so far `^(?!.*(359))` but it does not match everything other than the pattern.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: can you put in a few more examples along with their expected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd want:

```
\d((?:359)*)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2mHGVl/1)

---

- `\d` - A single digit;
- `((?:359)*)` - A 1st capture group to match '359' (greedy);
- `$` - End string anchor.

Replace with `*\1`

---

```
import re
s = "07440359359"
print(re.sub(r'\d((?:359)*)$', r'*\1', s))
```

Prints:

```
0744*359359
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a regex with capturing groups and a lookbehind?

```
s = "07440359359"

import re

out = re.sub(r'(\d+?)((?:359)+)', r'\1*\2', s)
```

output: `'07440*359359'`

If you want to ensure that the `359` are the last digits:

```
s = "074403593594"

import re

re.sub(r'(\d+?)((?:359)+)(?!\d)', r'\1*\2', s)
```

output: `074403593594`